# force window.print() to download a PDF

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, iframe

I made a feature for my website to let my users download the content of the site using these instructions: [Printing with Javascript || Mozilla Dev](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Printing). Basically the user is printing a new formated site stored in a hidden iframe. Now I want to let the user download that same PDF by clicking a button. Is there any easy way? I'm very happy with the result of **window.print()**.

I've taken a look a [jsPDF](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF) but it doesn't seem to be rendering my CSS correctly. Aditinally this library is pretty messy and hardly documented, I had to digg into the code, and I can't get it to work properly.

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to do it reliably client-side.  You could use PhantomJS or similar server-side to handle PDF generation.

If it were me, I'd just let the users do it themselves.  Chrome, for example, has a virtual printer driver which exports as a PDF.  For everyone else, there are print drivers available that do the same thing, such as CutePDF.